# SpriteKit - Border on all sides except bottom and top

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I have a main player node and enemies coming down randomly, but parts of them are outside the frame, I want to make it so they (and the player) are not able to get out of frame, left and right borders. How can I achieve that?

Thank you for your time and effort :)

Here's my enemy line, not sure how this can help but here it is so I don't get reported for being 'too broad'

```
 func launchEnemy() {

    let randomX = arc4random_uniform( UInt32(screenWidth))

    EnemyMissile.position = CGPoint(  x: CGFloat(randomX)  - (screenWidth / 2), y: screenHeight + 50)


    let action = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -400 + speedScore), duration: 5.0)


   EnemyMissile.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))        

     increaseSpeed()


    self.run(action, withKey:"LaunchEnemyAction")
}
```

*Here's my **EnemyClass***

```
     import Foundation
     import SpriteKit

class EnemyClass: SKNode {

var EnemyNode:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

var hitsToKill:Int = 2
var hitCount:Int = 0
var damagePoints: Int = 2

//var missileAnimation:SKAction?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) had not been implemented")

}

override init () {

    super.init()

}



    func createEnemy ( _ theImage:String) {


EnemyNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: theImage)
self.addChild(EnemyNode)

let body:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: EnemyNode.size.width / 2.25, center:CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0))
body.isDynamic = true
body.affectedByGravity = false
body.allowsRotation = false


  body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.enemy.rawValue
  body.contactTestBitMask =  BodyType.bullet.rawValue |              BodyType.player.rawValue


self.physicsBody = body

self.name = "EnemyClass"

}

func destroy() {
   self.removeFromParent()
   self.name = "removeNode"
}
func hit() -> Bool {

    hitCount += 1

    if ( hitCount == hitsToKill) {

        destroy()
        return true

    } else {
        damagePoints = 4

        EnemyNode.removeAction(forKey: "animation")
        return false
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You need to put some more work into this question,  try to create it where you can get a specific answer.  Explain what you have done and show some work,  the more thorough and concise the question, the better the answers will be.  I am going to give you some time to redo this before I vote to close for being to broad.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what do you mean? There isn't a specific 'issue' to solve, so I'm not sure how I can provide more information or 'work' to my question other than posting my entire GameScene which is completely unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Then you are in the wrong place. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to ask questions that fit this format.  Perhaps your broad question is better asked at https://developer.apple.com/devforums/ .

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I know that I am not in the wrong place, as I have been asking questions for a while here and I've seen many questions similar to this, being "broad", being answered. So sir, if you'll excuse me, I'm awaiting somebody who may help me in my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a -2 question to me @-@()

Comment: So the enemies can spawn with ½ their body being outside the frame and you also want a 'barrier' on the left and right sides that the enemies cannot pass through?

Comment: @SteveIves not only for the enemies but for the Player node as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have 2 issues:

1. Your spawning points are messed up
2. You have no boundary in place

You have a few options for setting boundaries, one being a physicsBody, another being `keepInBounds()` method or such. Below I should a simple keep in bounds method:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  func spawnEnemy() {
    let offset = CGFloat(5) // pixels, so enemy will have some spacing between borders.

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 100))
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    addChild(enemy)

    var randomX = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.width))) // This is not a perfect rando algo.

    // Because our random x was from 0 through screenwidth, but .position works
    // on -halfWidth through +halfWidth
    randomX -= (self.frame.size.width / 2)

    // Because spawning on the border will mean that the enemy is HALF out of view:
    /*

     right border:       |
     enemy @ frame.maxX: x
     - offset:          x|
     - size.w/2        x |
     */
    if randomX > self.frame.maxX - offset - (enemy.size.width / 2) {
       randomX = self.frame.maxX - offset - (enemy.size.width / 2)
    }
    else if randomX < self.frame.minX + offset + (enemy.size.width / 2) {
            randomX = self.frame.minX + offset + (enemy.size.width / 2)
    }

    enemy.position.x = randomX
  }

  func keepEnemyInBounds() {
    // A better way to do this would be to have a dictionary of enemies:
    for node in self.children {
      guard node.name == "enemy" else { continue }
      let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode

      if enemy.position.x > frame.maxX - (enemy.size.width / 2) {
        enemy.position.x = frame.maxX - (enemy.size.width / 2)
      }
      else if enemy.position.x < frame.minX + (enemy.size.width / 2) {
        enemy.position.x = frame.minX + (enemy.size.width / 2)
      }
    }
  }


  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    spawnEnemy()
  }
  override func didFinishUpdate() {
    keepEnemyInBounds()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This code doesn't work for me due to the fact that my enemy is referred as EnemyMissile which is from another class called EnemyClass, and because of that, when i insert "if randomX > self.frame.maxX - offset - (EnemyMissile.size.width / 2)..." etc., it says 'Value of type 'EnemyClass' has no member 'size'. I tried referencing EnemyNode inside of EnemyClass but it doesn't work. How can I get around that?

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy you have to use whichever property is the enemy spritenode instance. If EnemyMissile is a sprite, it should work. maybe post your classes so I can take a look?

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy oh wait, my code works inside of your GameScene, not your enemy class

Comment: It's complicated but basically the 'EnemyMissile' refers to EnemyClass, which contained the EnemyNode, which is the actual enemy sprite. And yes, I was putting your code in my GameScene, not EnemyClass. I'm going to post my EnemyClass to the description of this question for your reference.

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy ok, using standard swift naming, with instances being camelCase, you want to do in my code is 'let enemy = enemyMissile.enemyNode' and it will work

Comment: Awesome! so the enemies ARE coming down in the border now, but theres an issue w/ this. There's too many (tens and tens, as opposed to 1 or two every few seconds) and none of them have any contact with the player node as it did before, they just go through the player. Any ideas?

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy you have to program that stuff. this was just an example to show you how to do what you asked. You should be able to integrate the concept shown here into your own project. if you are having issues with another problem, then you can post a new question specific to that issue :)

Comment: I'm happy to keep helping, but I think this question has been answered. Putting too much stuff in one question is confusing to others who are having this issue and find this question. @GabrielsGalaxy please mark accept this answer as a solution, and I will be on the lookout for your new question, or you can tag me here with a link to it :)

Comment: Of course! I apologize, you've done more than enough, thank you so much for your help! And yes, I'll create a new question later with that specific thing I asked you^. Thanks @Fluidity !

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy np, don't forget to +1 this too if you liked it ^-^